# ZeroMQ on Linux environment

Tags: zeromq

On official `ZMQ` website, there are references to `Windows`/`Linux` sources, and `Windows` installer (that contains binary .dll/.lib files).

I am able to use the Windows DLL, but cannot find the option to download binary files (.so) for Linux.

Where are the binaries available (without compiling on Linux machine)?
I have a c++ project that works well with additional dependency `libzmq-v120-mt-4_0_4.dll`,`libzmq-v120-mt-4_0_4.lib`, (compiles and run)  and looking to download same binaries to compile and run on `Linux` machine

Comment: For Debian...  http://zeromq.org/distro:debian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many different Linux OS variant and architecture available, so it might not a good idea just download one so from others.

Actually, you can build your own easily according to http://zeromq.org/build:sparc-linux. Personally, I successfully built one before with following steps (you can change the ZeroMQ version accordingly)

```
cd /tmp/
git clone https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq4-1.git
cd zeromq4-1/
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```